# Find A & C In Search Result

Tags: mongodb, math, indexing, tagging, database

I want to be able to add up to 10 tags to a record in a database (MongoDB) but I don't want to add 10 columns with the related indexes on each of them. So I thought I'd add the unique sum of these tags.

e.g. (with 6 tags)

```
|------------|
|value | tag |
|------------|
|1     |a    |
|2     |b    |
|4     |c    |
|8     |d    |
|16    |e    |
|32    |f    |
|------------|
```

e.g.

a + b = 3

b + c + d = 14

I then store just the sum of the value in Mongo.

These combinations are always unique and I can "reconstitute" them back into tags when pulled from persistent storage using iteration.

```
int tagSum
for each (tag in tagCollection.OrderDescending)
{
    if (tagSum >= (int)tag)
    {
        TagProperty.Add(targetAge);
        tagSum -= (int)tag;
    }
}
```

My problem however is that I thought there must be a mathematical formula that I could use to query for a specific tag e.g. find the "c tag" by passing in the value 4. I'm either wrong or I cannot find it.

I'm happy to go with the Multikeys solution in Mongo but I have a lot of other data to index and using 1 index instead of 10 would just be nicer‽

Comment: Cool idea to make the index simpler. Unfortunately, I don't think you can take advantage of the index if you have to calculate bitmasks.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a bitwise AND, like so: value & 4 != 0, or am I wrong? (You'd have to do this in a javascript where, which can't use indexes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multikeys is the right approach to this problem as it can find any document from the single index on the array without a table-scan.  In your case you can just put the appropriate selection of letters representing the tags into the array: `["a", "d", "e"]`.

In more complicated cases where each field could contain the same tag values, for example song names, album names, artist names, ... I sometimes add the tag phrase twice: once on its own and once with the field name pre-pended, e.g. `"artist:Hello"`.  Now I can search on the tag word occurring in any field OR the tag word occurring in a specific field and either way it will use the index to find matching records.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the tags a-f to an integer 0-5, call it `tagValue`, then the number you want is `1<<tagValue`.